# RecyclerView not generating list when it has a view above it

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

So I cannot make the RecyclerView generate the given list once I have another view above it. The view above it and the recycler view are both within a LinearLayout and which is the single child of a NestedScrollView (used for collapsing  the toolbar). Once RecyclerView is the only view in the fragment everything works as expected.

StocksCompleteListFragment.java

```
public class StocksCompleteListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        NestedScrollView sv = (NestedScrollView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_stocks_completelist, container, false);
        LinearLayout mylinear = (LinearLayout) sv.findViewById(R.id.mainLinear);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) mylinear.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        if (rv == null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        setupRecyclerView(rv);
        return sv;
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                getRandomSublist(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings, 30)));
    }

    private List<String> getRandomSublist(String[] array, int amount) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(amount);
        Random random = new Random();
        while (list.size() < amount) {
            list.add(array[random.nextInt(array.length)]);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
        private int mBackground;
        private List<String> mValues;

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public String mBoundString;

            public final View mView;
            public final ImageView mImageView;
            public final TextView mTextView;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return super.toString() + " '" + mTextView.getText();
            }
        }

        public String getValueAt(int position) {
            return mValues.get(position);
        }

        public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
            context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
            mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mBoundString = mValues.get(position);
            holder.mTextView.setText(mValues.get(position));

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheeseDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(CheeseDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, holder.mBoundString);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
                    .load(Cheeses.getRandomCheeseDrawable())
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(holder.mImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.size();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the layout xml fragment_stocks_completelist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/grayBackground"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I wonder if the RecyclerView's height is the problem.  Try setting it to 0dp with a layout_weight of 1.

Comment: Thanks @nasch. Doesn't work though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set

```
    android:fillViewport="true"
```

on your NestedRecyclerView. If you put it into the `CoordinatorLayout` then also specify the behavior (which you've already done)

Comment: It doesn't work for you? It did for me. I don't know if it is CoordinatorLayout affecting the size if the scrollview or the scrollview itself just tells its children to draw themselves in full size. But it did work with standard layout managers, both of them.