# RecyclerView not showing anything with a sibling view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I posted this yesterday as well, but did not get any response. Can no one help with this? Basically, when the RecyclerView is only view of a tabbed fragment it works perfectly. However, once I want to include other views as sibling of this RecyclerView (wrapped in a linearlayout which is in turn wrapper in a NestedScrollView), the RecyclerView does not generate anything (or does now show?). The other view shows up though. So any idea what I might be doing wrong? Am I not passing the correct view / reference to the adapter?

StocksCompleteListFragment.java

```
public class StocksCompleteListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        NestedScrollView sv = (NestedScrollView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_stocks_completelist, container, false);
        LinearLayout mylinear = (LinearLayout) sv.findViewById(R.id.mainLinear);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) mylinear.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        if (rv == null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        setupRecyclerView(rv);
        return sv;
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                getRandomSublist(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings, 30)));
    }

    private List<String> getRandomSublist(String[] array, int amount) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(amount);
        Random random = new Random();
        while (list.size() < amount) {
            list.add(array[random.nextInt(array.length)]);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
        private int mBackground;
        private List<String> mValues;

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public String mBoundString;

            public final View mView;
            public final ImageView mImageView;
            public final TextView mTextView;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return super.toString() + " '" + mTextView.getText();
            }
        }

        public String getValueAt(int position) {
            return mValues.get(position);
        }

        public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
            context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
            mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mBoundString = mValues.get(position);
            holder.mTextView.setText(mValues.get(position));

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheeseDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(CheeseDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, holder.mBoundString);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
                    .load(Cheeses.getRandomCheeseDrawable())
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(holder.mImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.size();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the layout xml fragment_stocks_completelist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/grayBackground"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView not generating list when it has a view above it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234492/recyclerview-not-generating-list-when-it-has-a-view-above-it). Please do not double post your question.

Comment: I did it because I didn't get any response there.

Comment: Your question is already out there and people will answer it if they can. Double posting is not only against the SO "code of conduct", it will also not win you more sympathy but quite the reverse.

Comment: Ok won't do it again :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use a custom LayoutManager - which measures its children (either **LinearLayoutManager** or **GridLayoutManager**):

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {
private static final String TAG = CustomLayoutManager.class.getCanonicalName();
// Number of columns to show in the grid
private static final int SPAN_COUNT = 2;

public CustomLayoutManager(final Context context) {
    super(context, SPAN_COUNT);
}

private final int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(final RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, final RecyclerView.State state,
                      final int widthSpec, final int heightSpec) {

    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        measureScrapChild(recycler, View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.
                        UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);


        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(final RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, final int widthSpec,
                               final int heightSpec, final int[] measuredDimension) {
    try {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(0);

        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);

            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);

            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```